# Cannot connect to REST Api using httplib2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just trying to execute a small code below , so as to print all the json object retrived from the restapi

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
(resp_headers, content) = h.request("http://content.gaurdianapis.com/search?q=obama&format=json")
print content
```

But I'm giving below error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    (resp_headers, content) = h.request("http://content.gaurdianapis.com/search?q=obama&format=json")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1593, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1335, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1263, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at content.gaurdianapis.com
```

Can anybody help me  out here ? If i'm attempting it from a browser it is getting opened , where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not misspelled guardianapis.com?

Comment: OMG!!! such a stupid mistake I did .. Thanks a lot!!!